# My ubuntu shuts down when not connected to charge without giving any warning despite having more than 50% charge

Tags: 16.04, power-management, shutdown, battery

I have an HP notebook which I had dual booted with Ubuntu 16.04
Initially, the laptop worked well for 4-5 months without any problem but since the past 1 month it automatically shuts down when not connected to charge despite having sufficient charge.
What should I do? Please help me out here.
Thanks,
Ayush

Comment: I started having the same problem when I upgraded to ubuntu 18.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your battery may be failing. I assume your laptop-charger is the correct one for the computer?
Hope the problem doesn't get any worse....!
Walsingham.